# Multiple choice questions concerning types in C, need someone to verify my answers

Tags: c, pointers, types, structure

this is the code

```
typedef struct{
   char valeur[40];
   struct comp*Suivant;
}complexe;
typedef struct{
   complexe* debut;
   int n;
}classes;
classes C[20];
```

**Question:** What's the type of these expressions? ( my answer included ):\

a/ C[i]  **answer:** type is classes

b/C[i].debut **answer:** type is complexe *

c/C[i].n **answer:** type is int

d/C.debut->suivant **answer:** type is complexe *

e/C.debut->valeur[i] **answer:** type is character

f/*(C.debut) **answer:** type is complexe **

Which ones I got right and which ones I got wrong?

Comment: d, e, f are ill-formed because `C` is an array so `C.debut` won't compile. Even then `suivant` is not a field of any field, and `struct comp*` is not defined. `*(c->debut)` would be of type `complexe` rather than `complexe**`.

Comment: @PaulHankin oh yes, my bad `*(c.debut)` is the same as `c->debut` which is of type complexe not complexe **. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulHankin regarding the way the questions were asked, I didn't understand your remarks honestly haha, I didn't come up with the questions. What do you mean by "field"?